# set_xticks in bar chart for groups of data categories

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, axis-labels

I have a dataframe with five columns [CAT_LET, fid, input, climate change, terrestrial acidification].

In my real dataset there are:

- 6 values for CAT_LET = ['veg', 'fruit',...],
- 3871 for fid= [1,2,...],
- 12 for input = ['kgN', 'urea',...],
- and the corresponding values for two environmental impacts: climate change and terrestrial acidification.

The code makes a stacked bar graph scaled to 100% for each impact (with the contribution of each input for each fid) and should organize the bar per CAT_LET and fid.

Now I need to add the x labels to the graph where I can see each of the 6 CAT_LET values for groups of fid that vary in length. In my example I expect veg to appear in x for fids 1,3 and 5 and fruit for 2 and 4.
Any idea how to add these ticks and labels?

In my real dataset I do not want all 3871 fid to get the category name on the x label but only the groups with the same category appear (they should be together).

Thanks for the help.

```
    import pylab as pb
    from glob import glob
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

All_impacts_cat2 = pd.DataFrame()

All_impacts_cat2 = pd.DataFrame({'CAT_LET':['veg','veg','fruit','fruit','veg','veg','veg','fruit','veg','fruit','veg','fruit','fruit','veg','veg'], 
'fid': [5,1,4,2,3,1,5,2,3,4,1,2,4,3,5], 
'input':['urea','urea','kgN','urea','urea','kgN','kgN','kgN','kgN','urea','manure','manure','manure','manure','manure'], 
'climate change': [1,0,15,10,1,20,1,1,10,15,4,10,15,3,2], 
'terrestrial acidification': [0,1,10,10,2,1,2,10,1,15,4,20,25,3,2]})

impact_list = ['terrestrial acidification','climate change']
inputs = ['urea', 'kgN','manure']

for impact in impact_list[:1]:
values_list = []
for x in inputs:
    values_list.append(All_impacts_cat2.loc[All_impacts_cat2['input']==x].sort_values(by=['CAT_LET','fid'])[impact].values)

labels = [*range(0,len(values_list[0]))]
width = 0.35    

sum_values = np.zeros(np.shape(np.array(values_list[0]))) 
sum_total = np.zeros(np.shape(np.array(values_list[0])))
   
fig, ax = pb.subplots(figsize=(11,10))

for i in range(len(inputs)):
    sum_total = sum_total + np.array(values_list[i])
sum_total[sum_total ==0] = 1

for i in range(len(inputs)):
    data = values_list[i]/sum_total
    ax.bar(labels, data, width, label=inputs[i], bottom =sum_values)
    sum_values = sum_values + np.array(data)

ax.set_ylabel(impact)
ax.legend()
pb.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code - indentation is code. Include your imports - we can guess what `pb` is but maybe we are wrong. Provide a [minimal dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) that reflects your problem. Currently, the problem is rather [difficult to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry it wasn't really reproducible. I hope the small test I made works a bit better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix, you could collect the unique values for each `fid` and use them to label the x-positions of the bars.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

All_impacts_cat2 = pd.DataFrame({'CAT_LET':['veg','veg','fruit','fruit','veg','veg','veg','fruit','veg','fruit','veg','fruit','fruit','veg','veg'], 
'fid': [5,1,4,2,3,1,5,2,3,4,1,2,4,3,5], 
'input':['urea','urea','kgN','urea','urea','kgN','kgN','kgN','kgN','urea','manure','manure','manure','manure','manure'], 
'climate change': [1,0,15,10,1,20,1,1,10,15,4,10,15,3,2], 
'terrestrial acidification': [0,1,10,10,2,1,2,10,1,15,4,20,25,3,2]})

impact_list = ['terrestrial acidification','climate change']
inputs = ['urea', 'kgN','manure']

for impact in impact_list[:1]:
    values_list = []
    for x in inputs:
        values_list.append(All_impacts_cat2.loc[All_impacts_cat2['input']==x].sort_values(by=['CAT_LET','fid'])[impact].values)

labels = [*range(0,len(values_list[0]))]
width = 0.35    

sum_values = np.zeros(np.shape(np.array(values_list[0]))) 
sum_total = np.zeros(np.shape(np.array(values_list[0])))
   
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,10))

for i in range(len(inputs)):
    sum_total = sum_total + np.array(values_list[i])
sum_total[sum_total ==0] = 1

for i in range(len(inputs)):
    data = values_list[i]/sum_total
    ax.bar(labels, data, width, label=inputs[i], bottom =sum_values)
    sum_values = sum_values + np.array(data)
    
#get all unique CAT_LET entries for each fid
cat_groups = All_impacts_cat2["CAT_LET"].groupby(All_impacts_cat2["fid"]).unique().apply(list)
#relabel the x-ticks
ax.set_xticks(range(cat_groups.size), cat_groups)

ax.set_ylabel(impact)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

This approach takes into account that (although implied by your sample dataframe) not one `fid` value is mapped to exactly one `CAT_LET` value (for instance, change the first `veg` to `fruit`). If each `fid` has exactly one `CAT_LET` entry assigned, then you could simplify your approach.
Please also note that I have removed `pylab` from your code as [its use is now discouraged by matplotlib.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#module-pylab)